# Import Vue Component only when added to blade pages

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, components, laravel-blade

i'm starting to develop an app using Laravel, Vuejs, and blade for template engine.
Firstly, i'm new in Vuejs's world, and maybe is a simple task, but i didn't find an answer in any discussion.
The core idea is to use .blade page, and, when i need vuejs components, add them in the page passing server's data with props array. Everything's working fine, but after playing around for a bit, i've noticed one probably furure problem. 
In the laravel's documentation, we register the component, or whatever Vue setting in app.js: then, using laravel mix, we boundle in a single file all the code(e.g imports, requires, different js pages...), and finally we load "app.[hash].js" in our page with a script tag. I've noticed that even only using a few vue components, app.js growing very fast(of course, we import every components in one file), even dinamically importing components and not setting them globally. 
My question is: is normal to boundle all js code in a single file(having a large file), or is there a way to import vue component only when they are added in the .blade files, maybe with some sort of webpack(laravel mix) setting?

Thanks in advance for any support.

Found the solution after post the question:

Marcin and GoogleMac's answer might be both right, but i found an interesting topic about that, and i 'd want to share for anyone could have my problem. I suggest to check out this link https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/07/16/Lazy-load-in-Vue-using-Webpack-s-code-splitting/, where they talk about code splitting.
I think this could be the best approach, mostly because even in vue's documentation talks about(detail here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components).
My bad for haven't checked in detail documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to bundle js code in a single file because it's going to be downloaded only one time by the browser and cached.

JavaScript code is not that *that* big so don't bother yourself with it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marcin's answer, but if you are wanting a workaround, comment out Laravel's built in Vue registration in app.js and just use a cdn in your blade files.

Answer (score 0):

You may add multiple `app.js` (including multiple `router, vuex` if needed).
Entry them separately on `webpack.mix.js`.
And then include suitable `app.js` file as needed in the blade file. 
It's much easier I think if you don't want share some `.js` code with any user who will not use those component ever.

NB: Of course lazy loading is a solution, but that this is more convenient solution to me as I'll not deliver any component to the user who don't need it.